# Selenium with SauceLabs webdriver in python sets desired_capabilities to None

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I'm attempting to convert my SauceLabs executed Selenium 1.0 test to Selenium 2.0. When I create the selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver object:

```
driver = RemoteWebDriver('http://saucelabs.com:444', DesiredCapbilities.CHROME)
```

I can check if it was created properly, and the desired_capabilities seem to be set to none instead of being a dictionary.

This is causing problems after we create the selenium object, and call selenium.start(driver=driver):

```
selenium = selenium(host, port, browser_string, endpoint)
selenium.start(driver=driver)
```

The error I get is:

```
id = driver.desired_capabilities['webdriver.remote.sessionid']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to instantiate a selenium object or call .start with WebDriver. Just start calling methods on the Remote WebDriver object, like so:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
        command_executor="http://username:accesskey@ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub")
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_id(...etc...)
```